# Associated records via custom query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models that are connected via a has_many/belongs_to association:

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

Class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Each of the tasks are tagged with a HABTM relationship:

```
Class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

I am trying to get a list of projects based on a tag id.  I can get a list of projects that have tasks with a specific tag by using a class method on my `Project` model:

```
def by_tag(tag_id)
  Project.joins(:tasks => :tags).where(:tags => {:id = tag_id})
end
```

Ideally, I'm looking to be able to list all the projects and their associated tasks for a given tag in my view.  I could normally get a list of tasks belonging to a given project by using `project.tasks` if I used a typical find with project like `Project.find(1)`.

However, when I try `project.tasks` on results found using my new class method `Project.by_tag(1)`, I get a "NoMethodError: Undefined Method 'tasks'" error.

I looked into Named Scopes to get the Project by Tag results but it seems like people are moving away from that approach in favor of class methods.  Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

On your project model you need to add it to the class not the instance. Also note that this raises the self object to the class so you can eliminate "Project." unless you want to be explicit.

```
class << self
  def by_tag(tag_id)
    joins(:tasks => :tags).where(:tags => {:id = tag_id})
  end
end
```

There is always debate over what is the best method. I myself prefer whatever gets the job done quicker. I like scopes personally but to each his own.

Comment: Where do I find the class << self?

Would scopes handle this task more effectively?

Comment: Nevermind... I found it and `Project.by_tag(1)` gets me the same results I had before.  I still can't get `Project.by_tag(1).tasks` to list the tagged tasks.